# Why is docker-machine throwing a fatal error: bsdthread_register error?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Upgraded to Mac 12.0.1 recently, and my docker-machine command is throwing this error for any command.

My Docker version is 20.10.10, build b485636.

```
>>> docker-machine --version

fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x1689020, 0x21)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:527 +0x90 fp=0x7ff7bfeff8d0 sp=0x7ff7bfeff8b8
runtime.goenvs()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os1_darwin.go:73 +0x8d fp=0x7ff7bfeff8f8 sp=0x7ff7bfeff8d0
runtime.schedinit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc1.go:60 +0x83 fp=0x7ff7bfeff940 sp=0x7ff7bfeff8f8
runtime.rt0_go(0x7ff7bfeff978, 0x2, 0x7ff7bfeff978, 0x0, 0x1000, 0x2, 0x7ff7bfeffb28, 0x7ff7bfeffb37, 0x0, 0x7ff7bfeffb41, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:109 +0x132 fp=0x7ff7bfeff948 sp=0x7ff7bfeff940
```

Any idea how to resolve this? Been stuck here for awhile, any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reinstall it because it needs new binaries?

Comment: @LinFelix Originally installed using `pip install docker-machine`, doesn't seem to work anymore